# table of strings array

Tags: c++, arrays

```
#include <iostream>
#include "HtmlTable.h"
using namespace std;


int main()
{
   cout << "Content-type: text/html" << endl << endl;
   HtmlTable t(2,3);


   t.insert(2,1, "one");
   t.insert(1,2, "two");
   t.insert(2,3, "three");
   t.print();

   return 0;
}
```

---

```
#ifndef HTMLTABLE_H
#define HTMLTABLE_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class HtmlTable
{
public:
    HtmlTable(int y, int x)
    {
    }


    void print()
    {
        cout << "<table>";
        for (row=0; row<y; row++)
        {
            cout << "<tr>";
            for (col=0; col<x; col++)
            {
                cout << "<table border='1'>";
                cout << m_Table[y][x];

            }
            cout << "</td>";
        }
        cout << "</table>";


    }

    void insert(int row, int col, string text)
    {
        y = row;
        x = col;
        z = text;
        m_Table[y][x] = {{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z}};
    }


protected:
private:
    string m_Table[100][100];

    int row;
    int col;
    string text;
    int x;
    int y;
    string z;
    int get_x = x;
    int get_y = x;

};




#endif // HTMLTABLE_H
```

---

I have to create a 2d array of strings. 
There is an insert function that inserts a string into a certain spot in the array.
Then the print function should print a table with the words inside the corresponding box.
output should be something like this:

---

### |____| two |______|

### | one|_____| three|

I am given int main and cant change anything.

My current issue is with the void insert. the error is:

> no match for 'operator=' in
>   '((HtmlTable*)this)->HtmlTable::m_Table[((HtmlTable*)this)->HtmlTable::y]

my past attemps only printed the last spring and repeated in for every box in the table.
what am i doing the array incorrectly? is my print function also incorrect?

Comment: `m_Table[y][x]` is *one* string. You can't assign a two-dimensional initializer list to it. To find out why your past attempt only printed the same string all over, think about which string you're outputting with `cout << m_Table[y][x];` in each loop iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
m_Table[y][x] = {{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z},{z,z,z,z}};
```

is plain wrong. `m_Table` is a 2D array or strings, so `m_Table[y][x]` is just a `std::string`. You should write: `m_Table[y][x] = z`.

But there are many other problems in your code:

- you pass the array dimensions in `HtmlTable` constructor but ignore them
- you declare `z, row, col, text` as member variable when they does not store state: they should be local variable of member functions
- these two lines

  ```
  int get_x = x;
  int get_y = x;
  ```

  declare unused member variable and try to initialize them which is incorrect. Member variables should be initialized in constructor (except for integral static const ones)
- `print` make `row` loop from 0 to `y`, and `col` from 0 to `x` (which is right if `x` and `y` are initialized), but consistently writes `m_Table[y][x]` instead of `m_Table[row][col]`

And your `print` method is wrong... because you never initialized x and y. Your constructor should be:

```
HtmlTable(int y, int x): x(x), y(y)
{
}
```

and you should not modify them in insert:

```
void insert(int row, int col, string text)
{
    m_Table[row][col] = text;
}
```

Array are 0 indexed in C++. Your main should contain:

```
t.insert(1,0, "one");
t.insert(0,1, "two");
t.insert(1,2, "three");
```

BTW, generated HTML is incorrect: you do not close `<tr>` tag, not open `<td>` one, and nest `<table>` tags in a strange way but this would be another story...

Comment: it still gives me 12 "one".  "one" is printed in all the boxes

Comment: I know the strings are placed correctly in the array, because when i just print without the loop and i specify the array i want, it prints the correct string. but if i use the loop it prints the last string to be added to the array and prints it in all the boxes.

Comment: @R4g323: I fixed it first in my test because I found it obvious and forgot to note it in my answer: you always write same value in loop! See my edit.